# What are the cognitive elements of dangerous behaviors?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, abnormal-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience

I am looking for theories or articles that focused on cognitive elements contributing to risk-taking behaviors. For example it is known that response inhibition is linked to impulsive behaviors.
I am looking for any neurocognitive parameters that meet criteria of antisocial personality disorder in DSM-5, especially including impairments in self-functioning such as:

> Self-direction: Goal-setting based on personal gratification; absence of prosocial internal standards associated with failure to conform to lawful or culturally normative ethical behavior.

Comment: How are you defining "cognitive elements" (personality traits; information processing; contextual factors like alcohol and drug use and how they operate)? What risk taking behaviours are you interested in (e.g., driving fast; engaging in contact sports; aggression; extreme sports; etc.)?

Comment: Actually I am looking for any neurocognetive parameters that meet criteria of antisocial personality disorder in DSM-5 especially Impairments in self functioning such as Self-direction: Goal-setting based on personal gratification; absence of prosaically internal standards associated with failure to conform to lawful or culturally normative ethical behavior.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm still not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by neurocognitive parameters? How do they relate to cognitive elements? How does this concern with the DSM 5 antisocial personality disorder relate to the previous question.

Answer (score 2):

There are correlations betweeen risk behaviours and temperament traits. According to Strelau's theory of temperament (1998) people are devided into those who have low and high demand for stimulation. The second one will probably do risk behaviours more often. There are also anothar temperament traits which can influence sb's behaviour.

You can read more there:
Strelau (1998) Temperament: A Psychological Perspective

And some other scientific articles with research results:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0376871603003570
http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/psp/73/5/1052/

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask u to forward this 2 article to me?

Comment: @Dena: It's [a book](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=jMt2fUXCFKoC&oi=fnd&pg=PT15&dq=Temperament:+A+Psychological+Perspective&ots=3Tn6K8v7Mc&sig=lQXw6bTRkzbupU3B9EB44tR62ME#v=onepage&q=Temperament%3A%20A%20Psychological%20Perspective&f=false), so probably not!

Comment: I haven't got these materials on my computer but you can find them on some online bases with scientific articles or maybe in pdf? You have to check.